# Crystal reports asks for login instead of parameters popup

Tags: c#, winforms, crystal-reports, report

I have a crystal report which contains parameters to enter. It worked perfectly and display data needed. But today it doesn't work any more: when i try to open the report, the popup don't ask for parameters. It asks for: server, user name and password.
I don't change any thing in database... 
And i can't identify the problem exactly.
Thank you.

Comment: Odds are when you ran the report yesterday that machine was already logged into the system you're trying to connect to. You'll need to log in again today.

Comment: no there is no login to do!

Comment: the other reports (without parameters) work perfectly.

Comment: Finally i got the problem: VS can't get crdbadoplus.dll. But i have it in my references loaded from "C:\Program Files (x86)\SAP BusinessObjects\Crystal Reports for .NET Framework 4.0\Common\SAP BusinessObjects Enterprise XI 4.0\win32_x86\dotnet". In the error it's announced that this .dll is not found at ""C:\Program Files (x86)\SAP BusinessObjects\Crystal Reports for .NET Framework 4.0\Common\SAP BusinessObjects Enterprise XI 4.0\win32_x86\dotnet1". The folder "dotnet1" does not exist! Any suggestion plz!